# MaterializeCSS slider slide missing active class after first slide

Tags: slider, materialize

I am using the materialize css slider. The first slide works fine. When it moves to the next slide it stops adding the .active class.

I have the basic setup. What happens after the first slide is shown is that it doesn't move to the next one. Look at the image. Velocity stays buzzy on the first slide and never adds an .active class to any other slide anymore. Not even the first.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why? It worked 2 days ago without issues. Something that i changed in JS must have broken this but i can't seem to figure out why.
Maybe somebody had this situation before? Hope you can help me out.

Cheers,

Victor

Comment: I found out that VideoJS interferes with materializecss. If loaded after materializecss. When i am able to fix it, i'll drop a note here.

Answer (score 0):

I found that VideoJS does not work in combination with VideoJS. Both use Slider class, and therefor conflicts occur.
If you are able to strip Slider from either one of the 2 then your good I guess. For me, ... it was way to much work so I downgraded to HTML5 native  :)

Comment: Can you explain about VideoJS not working in combination with VideoJS. Then it might be a good answer.